# How to compare 2 dataTables

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have 2 datatables and I just want to know if they are the same or not. By "the same", I mean do they have exactly the same number of rows with exactly the same data in each column, or not.  I'd love to write (find) a method which accepts both tables and returns a boolean.

How can I compare 2 datatables in this way?  Both have identical schemas.

Comment: This has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164144/c-how-to-compare-two-datatables-a-b-how-to-show-rows-which-are-in-b-but-not  The question is not EXACTLY the same.  In your case you'd need to loop through the rows, and within that loop, loop through the columns in teh row to compare values.

Comment: @DavidStratton -Sorry, this is not the same question.

Comment: What is the purpose for wanting to do this to give it some context?

Comment: I know that's why I didn't vote to close.   I edited my comment.  This post shows how to do it, following the general advice of my edited comment: http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html

Comment: @CodeBlend -I'm comparing the original table with a possibly modified version of that same table.  If nothing has changed, I want to print a report, if something has changed, I want to update the values then print the report.

Comment: @Shredder -No, I can write such a loop.  It seems inefficient, so I asked to see if anyone had a better way.

Comment: @MAW74656 What is your datasource for the datatables?

Comment: @CodeBlend -I've written a stored procedure and I use SQLCommand object and SqlDataAdapter to fill the table.

Comment: FYI in case you are just trying to "get the job done" there ARE some commercial tools that will do this... RedGate has two products - SQLCompare for the schema and SQLDataCompare for the data.  Very nice tools.  But since that would assume that this is a "non-programming" question I assume that's not what you were looking for.

Comment: Maybe my answer will prove useful, it is what I have seen others use to determine if there are changes from the original dataset

Comment: @MichaelBray -These sound like they would not work for me, I want to do comparison without involved SQL server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to loop through the rows of each table, and then through each column within that loop to compare individual values.

There's a code sample here: http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html

Comment: -I used this and wrote a public method to call the code and return the boolean.  See edit for code used.

Comment: The link sample code only works with 32 columns or less. Otherwise you get a "Cannot have more than 32 columns" error.

Answer (score 31):

```
 public static bool AreTablesTheSame( DataTable tbl1, DataTable tbl2)
 {
    if (tbl1.Rows.Count != tbl2.Rows.Count || tbl1.Columns.Count != tbl2.Columns.Count)
                return false;


    for ( int i = 0; i < tbl1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for ( int c = 0; c < tbl1.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            if (!Equals(tbl1.Rows[i][c] ,tbl2.Rows[i][c]))
                        return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: -Yes, I understand how this could work.  I might see if its faster than the other option.  PizzaTime!

Comment: The code is not compilable, and also should use !Equals instead of '!=' operator. See post http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2013/08/27/methods-to-verify-are-datatables-or-datasets-the-same.aspx

Answer (score 24):

If you were returning a DataTable as a function you could:

```
DataTable dataTable1; // Load with data
DataTable dataTable2; // Load with data (same schema)

// Fast check for row count equality.
if ( dataTable1.Rows.Count != dataTable2.Rows.Count) {
    return true;
}

var differences =
    dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable2.AsEnumerable(),
                                            DataRowComparer.Default);

return differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
```

Comment: Not bad at all, this

Comment: But when you remove a row from a table, the difference does not show. hmm!

Comment: @netfed I updated the answer with a check to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: There is an edge case here if the two tables do not have primary keys - a duplicate row in the first table, plus a different row in the second table. If you need a stronger guarantee and tables might not have primary keys (or in other words, could contain duplicates), then the Except needs to be run twice (table1 except table2, and table2 except table1).

Answer (score 7):

The OP, [MAW74656](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456532/maw74656), originally posted this answer in the question body in response to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518025/211627), as explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517968/how-to-compare-2-datatables/7518025#comment9105363_7518025):

> I used this and wrote a public method to call the code and return the boolean.

**The OP's answer:**

> Code Used:
>
> ```
> public bool tablesAreTheSame(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
> {
>     DataTable dt;
>     dt = getDifferentRecords(table1, table2);
>
>     if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> }
>
> //Found at http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-compare-two-datatables-in-adonet.html
> private DataTable getDifferentRecords(DataTable FirstDataTable, DataTable SecondDataTable)
> {
>     //Create Empty Table     
>     DataTable ResultDataTable = new DataTable("ResultDataTable");
>
>     //use a Dataset to make use of a DataRelation object     
>     using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
>     {
>         //Add tables     
>         ds.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { FirstDataTable.Copy(), SecondDataTable.Copy() });
>
>         //Get Columns for DataRelation     
>         DataColumn[] firstColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
>         for (int i = 0; i < firstColumns.Length; i++)
>         {
>             firstColumns[i] = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i];
>         }
>
>         DataColumn[] secondColumns = new DataColumn[ds.Tables[1].Columns.Count];
>         for (int i = 0; i < secondColumns.Length; i++)
>         {
>             secondColumns[i] = ds.Tables[1].Columns[i];
>         }
>
>         //Create DataRelation     
>         DataRelation r1 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, firstColumns, secondColumns, false);
>         ds.Relations.Add(r1);
>
>         DataRelation r2 = new DataRelation(string.Empty, secondColumns, firstColumns, false);
>         ds.Relations.Add(r2);
>
>         //Create columns for return table     
>         for (int i = 0; i < FirstDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
>         {
>             ResultDataTable.Columns.Add(FirstDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, FirstDataTable.Columns[i].DataType);
>         }
>
>         //If FirstDataTable Row not in SecondDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.     
>         ResultDataTable.BeginLoadData();
>         foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
>         {
>             DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r1);
>             if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
>                 ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
>         }
>
>         //If SecondDataTable Row not in FirstDataTable, Add to ResultDataTable.     
>         foreach (DataRow parentrow in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
>         {
>             DataRow[] childrows = parentrow.GetChildRows(r2);
>             if (childrows == null || childrows.Length == 0)
>                 ResultDataTable.LoadDataRow(parentrow.ItemArray, true);
>         }
>         ResultDataTable.EndLoadData();
>     }
>
>     return ResultDataTable;
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried this and it maxes out at 32 columns at DataRelation.

Comment: Same issue i.e. "maxes out at 32 columns" facing when used that getDifferentRecords method... but it workes in less column..

Answer (score 6):

Try to make use of linq to Dataset

```
(from b in table1.AsEnumerable()  
    select new { id = b.Field<int>("id")}).Except(
         from a in table2.AsEnumerable() 
             select new {id = a.Field<int>("id")})
```

Check this article : [Comparing DataSets using LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Comparing_Datasets.aspx)

Comment: -I didn't specify this in the question (hence the +1), but I want to avoid LINQ so I can run on workstations with .NET 2.0.  Yes, its lame, but its sort of a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620698/2390270
    /// Compare a source and target datatables and return the row that are the same, different, added, and removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dtOld">DataTable to compare</param>
    /// <param name="dtNew">DataTable to compare to dtOld</param>
    /// <param name="dtSame">DataTable that would give you the common rows in both</param>
    /// <param name="dtDifferences">DataTable that would give you the difference</param>
    /// <param name="dtAdded">DataTable that would give you the rows added going from dtOld to dtNew</param>
    /// <param name="dtRemoved">DataTable that would give you the rows removed going from dtOld to dtNew</param>
    public static void GetTableDiff(DataTable dtOld, DataTable dtNew, ref DataTable dtSame, ref DataTable dtDifferences, ref DataTable dtAdded, ref DataTable dtRemoved)
    {
        try
        {
            dtAdded = dtOld.Clone();
            dtAdded.Clear();
            dtRemoved = dtOld.Clone();
            dtRemoved.Clear();
            dtSame = dtOld.Clone();
            dtSame.Clear();
            if (dtNew.Rows.Count > 0) dtDifferences.Merge(dtNew.AsEnumerable().Except(dtOld.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>());
            if (dtOld.Rows.Count > 0) dtDifferences.Merge(dtOld.AsEnumerable().Except(dtNew.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>());
            if (dtOld.Rows.Count > 0 && dtNew.Rows.Count > 0) dtSame = dtOld.AsEnumerable().Intersect(dtNew.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dtDifferences.Rows)
            {
                if (dtOld.AsEnumerable().Any(r => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(r.ItemArray, row.ItemArray))
                    && !dtNew.AsEnumerable().Any(r => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(r.ItemArray, row.ItemArray)))
                {
                    dtRemoved.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                }
                else if (dtNew.AsEnumerable().Any(r => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(r.ItemArray, row.ItemArray))
                    && !dtOld.AsEnumerable().Any(r => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(r.ItemArray, row.ItemArray)))
                {
                    dtAdded.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or this, I did not implement the array comparison so you will also have some fun :)

```
public bool CompareTables(DataTable a, DataTable b)
{
    if(a.Rows.Count != b.Rows.Count)
    {
        // different size means different tables
        return false;
    }

    for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<a.Rows.Count; ++rowIndex)
    {
        if(!arraysHaveSameContent(a.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray, b.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray,))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Tables have same data
    return true;
}

private bool arraysHaveSameContent(object[] a, object[] b)
{
    // Here your super cool method to compare the two arrays with LINQ,
    // or if you are a loser do it with a for loop :D
}
```

Comment: @Davide Piras -Loser's use loops?  What if your programming against something less than .NET 3.5?  That's harsh man.

Comment: yep, it was a joke and I have put a big :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using a DataTable at all then rather than comparing two 'DataTables' could you just compare the DataTable that is going to have changes with the original data when it was loaded AKA [DataTable.GetChanges Method (DataRowState)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by **samneric**'s answer using **DataRowComparer.Default** but needing something that would only compare a subset of columns within a DataTable, I made a **DataTableComparer** object where you can specify which columns to use in the comparison. Especially great if they have different columns/schemas.

**DataRowComparer.Default** works because it implements IEqualityComparer. Then I created an object where you can define which columns of the DataRow will be compared.

```
public class DataTableComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    private IEnumerable<String> g_TestColumns;
    public void SetCompareColumns(IEnumerable<String> p_Columns)
    {
        g_TestColumns = p_Columns; 
    }

    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {

        foreach (String sCol in g_TestColumns)
            if (!x[sCol].Equals(y[sCol])) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        StringBuilder hashBuff = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (String sCol in g_TestColumns)
            hashBuff.AppendLine(obj[sCol].ToString());               

        return hashBuff.ToString().GetHashCode();

    }
}
```

You can use this by:

```
DataTableComparer comp = new DataTableComparer();
comp.SetCompareColumns(new String[] { "Name", "DoB" });

DataTable celebrities = SomeDataTableSource();
DataTable politicians = SomeDataTableSource2();

List<DataRow> celebrityPoliticians = celebrities.AsEnumerable().Intersect(politicians.AsEnumerable(), comp).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about merging 2 data tables and then comparing the changes? Not sure if that will fill 100% of your needs but for the quick compare it will do a job.

```
public DataTable GetTwoDataTablesChanges(DataTable firstDataTable, DataTable secondDataTable)
{ 
     firstDataTable.Merge(secondDataTable);
     return secondDataTable.GetChanges();
}
```

You can read more about DataTable.Merge()

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you have the tables in a database, you can make a full outer join to get the differences. Example:

```
select t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t2.Field1, t2.Field2
from Table1 t1
full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.Field1 = t2.Field1 and t1.Field2 = t2.Field2
where t1.Field1 is null or t2.Field2 is null
```

All records that are identical are filtered out. There is data either in the first two or the last two fields, depending on what table the record comes from.

Comment: -I want to do comparison without involved SQL server (trying to save a round trip to DB), so this would not be suitable for me in this case.

Comment: this question is to compare two datatables. The data could come from different sources of databases.