# Getting difference in 2 datasets

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset

I'm making an application in which i have 2 datasets in C#. I have 2 datasets because I put all the returned tables from a MySQL request into an dataset but I also have a dataset that includes all the created datatables from an XML file (this file is created when there is an internet connection the first time the application is run).

I have done it this way so I can also work offline with this application, however if I debug the application which has the following code then the application will always say that there are no changes:

```
public DataSet Changed(DataSet set1, DataSet set2)
    {
       DataSet end = new DataSet();

       end.Merge(set1);
       end.AcceptChanges();
       end.Merge(set2);

       DataSet changes = end.GetChanges();

        return changes;
    }
```

The dataset that is returned is always false, even if I manually edit an XML file and change a number, so I'm now wondering how I could make this work so I can firstly find out if the two datasets are different, and secondly which holds the difference and what is changed so that I can either update the XML file or update/insert the change in the database.

### Edit

I found out that the names were different so instead of 7 tables he consisted of 14 tables, now I only ran into the problem:

```
target . and source . have conflicting properties datatype property mismatch.
```

Now I'm wondering what is going wrong since the XML is a pure rip still from the database and the other is just a result from the database.

Comment: Try reading [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055909/get-the-differences-in-2-datasets-c-sharp), it seems similar enough.

Comment: only one problem that a solution that was posted is already in the code

Comment: The answer is what you want to read - basically compare record-by-record.