# Compare Excel data with microsoft SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have an excel sheet with customer data : firstname, lastname, dob, streetname1, streetname2, city and I want to compare the data with our SQL Server database.

If the fields in the excel match the data in SQL, then I want to return the SQL row.

Can anyone advice on how to do this? I tried loading the data into two datatables, and compare, but I am unable to achieve what I want so I am wondering if there is a different way.

The issue with the datatables is linked to this [DataRelation Compare tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345111/datarelation-how-to-compare-specific-columns) would appreciate some guidance on this

Unfortunately I don't have access to importing the excel data into the database so it should be done externally.

Comment: I think you need to join the DataTables (or database columns) so the fields from the SQL query are the same as the excel columns.

Comment: it's not a good idea to compare the data in `Server-Side` as you will hit a memory limitation issue. I would suggest to transfer the data to the `Database` and then join the temp data with the main table using a primary field and then build your comparison logic.

Comment: Yes I agree @vikscool. no access from the vendor.

Comment: If you have access to query the data in the `Database` then i would suggest to query it using `FirstName`,`LastName`(*add any other field which can be used to uniquely identify the records in the DB*) from the excel sheet and then build your comparison logic afterwards.