# LINQ: Comparing specific values in two datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I have two datatables.

datatable 1 has data with columns FirstName, LastName, DOB, Gender
datatable 2 has data with columns CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Gender

I want to compare the firstName, LastName, DOB and gender in datatable 1 and 2, and if there is a match, load that row in datatable 2 into a new datatable.

Below is what I am using, I can compare with Firstname, but I want to add the lastname, DOB and gender. Please can you show me how I can do that?

I want to do it such that if firstname, lastname, dob and gender match then return that matching row in datatable 2. The column length between the tables are different.

```
DataTable dtMerged = (from a in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                  join b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  on a["Forename"].ToString() equals b["FirstName"].ToString()
                                  into g
                                  where g.Count() > 0
                                  select a).CopyToDataTable();

            dtMerged.AsDataView();
```

Comment: sorry @Anas, its not a duplicate. I did go through that answer but that one compares all columns, but I want to compare specific columns.

Comment: @edcoder yes it's duplicate indeed. may not be exact one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DataTable dtMerged = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(ra => dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(rb => rb.Field<string>("firstname") == ra.Field<string>("firstname")
      && rb.Field<string>("lastname") == ra.Field<string>("lastname")
      && rb.Field<DateTime>("dob") == ra.Field<DateTime>("dob")
      && rb.Field<string>("gender") == ra.Field<string>("gender")))
              .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thank You @Shyam. This works. Exactly what I wanted.