# How to create a DataTable that contains the comparaison result of two DataTables having the same structure?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, data-comparison

This question has already been asked several times on *Stack Overflow*, but before marking it as a duplicate, please have a look at my issue.

I am trying to compare two database tables for changed values.
Basically, I am trying to log updated data by comparing.

These are my database tables which need to be compared for changes:

[image: My DataTables]

In Table 2, `Id` 3 and 4 have got updated values. I need to get these values and store them in a 3rd database table.
It will be much better if I get some generic class for this.

Also, if anybody add some more and tell me how do I will compare for a change in case of 2 list of same type and return the list of that type only with changed values?

Here, I am asking for more but if somebody can help me out.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal? What is your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your dev environment and share more code or some screenshot of your screeen. To help you improve the content, title and tags of your query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* which is in the help center.

Comment: Is it not a possible duplicate of [How to compare 2 dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517968/how-to-compare-2-datatables) ?

Comment: I tried this but it's returning unwanted rows which I am not looking. I am only bothered of those rows which were changed. If I am creating a function for finding the diff then that function should return datatable containing only the changed values.

Comment: Can you add some code about the instances you want to control like datatables declarations and queries on them, please?

Comment: I have created a gist. Please check this out https://gist.github.com/Glennsingh44/251e88701dd28b46b87717fa58cf4fb0

Comment: My goal here is to create a generic class which can solve my problem of finding difference by using datatable or list. I found examples with datatable finding the differences but nothing is working for me.

Comment: You want to get a third datatable containing only a duplication of records found in dt1 and dt2 that have same id but where there is at least one different field? What do you call a `generic` class here? Does a method enough?

Comment: I begin to understand your goal, I think. But you can't create a data table to add rows that mismatch on values because of the ID that will be duplicated. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Let's forget about generic class. How can i achieve this with function.

Comment: @Glenn singh, please check solution in my answer if it fits your needs. Thanks.

Comment: @fenixil Sure I will try your answer as well. Thanks for that.But for the time being what Olivier Rogier has given, works for me. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

### Comparer

.net BCL contains abstractions that you can use to declare custom comparison that fits your needs:

```
class RowDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        // add check for nulls, different ItemArray length, whatever
        var xv = x.ItemArray;
        var yv = y.ItemArray;

        for (int i = 0; i < xv.Length; i++)
            if(xv[i] == null && yv[i] == null)
               continue; 
            else if (xv[i]==null || !xv[i].Equals(yv[i]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj) 
        => obj[0]?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
}
```

Few interesting things in this comparer you need to know about:

1) `GetHashCode` implementation is dumb and rather useless, but it works ;). Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode) to know how to implement it correctly. Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-used-for-is-it-unique/35217051) to know where it is used and if it is so critical to implement it in your case.

2) I do check values for `null`, because I hate `NullReferenceException`s. However, that might not be the case here, because null values in `DataRow` is replaced by `DBNull.Value`

3) I don't use operator `==` to compare objects. It might work fine for reference types which implement `Equals/GetHashCode`, otherwise it will compare references. Boxed values always have different references, so if you have for example integer columns, `==` will not work. Try this to feel the difference: `Console.WriteLine((object)42 == (object)42)` and `Console.WriteLine(((object)42).Equals((object)42))`

### Diffs

Assuming that schema is identical, keys are integers and you don't care about extra/missing rows you can use something like below:

```
class RowsComparer
{
    Dictionary<int, DataRow> _leftRows;
    Dictionary<int, DataRow> _rightRows;
    HashSet<int> _commonKeys;

    private static Dictionary<int, DataRow>  toRows(DataTable table)
        => table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToDictionary(r => (int)r.ItemArray[0]);

    public RowsComparer(DataTable left, DataTable right)
    {
        _leftRows = toRows(left);
        _rightRows = toRows(right);

        _commonKeys = new HashSet<int>(_leftRows.Keys.Intersect(_rightRows.Keys));
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> Diffs()
        => _commonKeys.Select(k => _rightRows[k]).Except(_leftRows.Values, new RowDataComparer());

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> Extra()
        => _leftRows.Where(kv => !_commonKeys.Contains(kv.Key)).Select(kv => kv.Value);

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> Missing()
        => _rightRows.Where(kv => !_commonKeys.Contains(kv.Key)).Select(kv => kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: Compiler Error CS0266 *Impossible de convertir implicitement le type 'bool?' en 'bool'. Une conversion explicite existe (un cast est-il manquant ?)"

Comment: @Oliver, I updated the answer. I do really hope that you&#39;ll find it useful rather than just blindly copy-paste provided code ;) if you spot an error, you can also propose an edit. Anyway thanks for a note :)

Comment: Not sure I follow your question, but I guess the answer will be: similar to  other code - with unit-tests. Design is rather testable because concerns are separated, it is not ideal, probably I'd split comparers (or extract metho) to be able to match object arrays only and don't work with messy DataRows. Also I think data driven testing will fit here very well.

Comment: I use `var res = new RowsComparer(before, after); foreach ( var v in res.Diffs() ) Console.WriteLine(v["Id"]);`but I got `1 2 3 4`. So it seems your solution does not work.

Comment: That's actually a good catch! I added a link in the initial answer to the potential issue :) See `GetHashCode()` implementation.